# Открытие URL с помощью shellExecute в win 10 не срабатывает в случае передачи PCHAR

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE 7
В общем есть код который работает и на win 7 и на win 10

```
shellExecute(self.Handle,'open','https://yandex.ru',nil,nil,SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Но есть нужда открывать URL которые хранятся в переменной, делаю к примеру так:

```
link := 'https://yandex.ru';
shellExecute(self.Handle,'open',pchar(link),nil,nil,SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

На Win 7 срабатывает как надо, открывает браузер по указанному в **link** пути, Win 10 просто игнорирует, **подскажите что можно сделать?** Пробовал ShellExecuteEx, не помогло, он тупо считает что я пытаюсь открыть файл и говорит, что он не найден

Comment: Вам нужно использовать ASCIIz прибавляйте `#0` и с первого елемента pchar делайте.

Comment: какой тип у переменной link? Не shortstring случайно?

Comment: _"lpFile - A pointer to a **null-terminated string** that specifies the file"_ © [MSDN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) -> `link := 'https://ya.ru'#0;`, как уже было выше написано

Comment: @teran в этом нет необходимости. Явное приведение string к PChar, а равно и использование @link[1] - уже делает передаваемый параметр корректной нуль-терминированной строкой. Без необходимости явного добавления #0.

Comment: Для начала, кстати, можно получить код ошибки, который вернет ShellExecute

Comment: @kami тип string

Comment: В общем так и не получается открыть ссылку не смотря на все советы, возвращает код ошибки 2, поискал в инете пишут, что это "The specified file was not found". Т.е. он воспринимает URL в данном случае как файл и пытается найти его и открыть, но ведь это не файл, и когда передаю его не в переменной URL прекрасно открывается, не знаю что делать ( Подозреваю что это в WIN 10, что-то косякнули

Comment: @kami, чисто для справки: delphi хранит строки (которые просто string, а не AnsiString) с заключительным нулём в конце, именно для совместимости с PChar. По теме: посмотреть в реестре, что назначего обработчиком на 'open' для протокола 'https'.

Comment: @Alekcvp не знаю что, но если указать этот хттпс напрямую в экзекуте то открывается мс идж, проблема возникает именно при передачи через переменную урла

Comment: Все народ, разобрался, проблема была в том, что семерошному эксплореру плевать на лишние пробелы в URL! А EDGE браузер в 10 нет. По отладчику посмотрел внимательно, что у меня приходит в info_link и заметил пробел лишний, добавил info_link:=trim(info_link); и стало норм. Кто столкнется с такой же проблемой рекомендую проверить внимательно переменную!

Answer (score -1):

выше в комментах, основное вам уже ответили, вот еще процедура, в w10 работает (с учетом #0, еще string как вариант на ansistring заменить мона)

```
Procedure GuErr(const s:string);
begin
MessageBox(0,PChar(s),'Ошибка',Mb_ok+Mb_IconError+Mb_TopMost);
end;

Procedure GuRun(s:string;p:string='';d:string='');
var i:integer;
begin
if s='' then Exit;
Try
i:=ShellExecute(0,'open',pchar(s),pchar(p),pchar(d),SW_NORMAL);
if i<=32 then application.MessageBox(pchar('Code: '+pchar(inttostr(i)+', for '+d+s+' '+p)),'Error',mb_iconerror);
Except on e:exception do GuErr(e.Message);End;
end;
```

пример

```
GuRun('http://ya.ru');
GuRun('calc.exe');
GuRun('notepad.exe');
```

p,d необязательные параметры, см справку к ShellExecute - директория и параметры. 
заметьте, {if s='' then Exit;} тут нет {if not fileexist(s) then exit;} - тут зарыта более глубока проблема - с запуском x64 приложений и др ...

+

http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2015/01/never-use-ShellExecute.html

+

найти не могу

но "некоторые приложения не запускаются", как решение - добавление в процедуру в начало и конец строк, в заголовок r + соотв. процедуры в заголовок файла

```
//if IsWow64 then if r then Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(x);
....
//if IsWow64 then if r then Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(true);
```

Comment: `еще string как вариант на ansistring заменить мона` - не давайте деструктивных советов. Кастование AnsiString в PWideChar (учитываем, что работа ведется в XE7) пройдет на ура, но вот ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет.

Comment: @Gu К сожалению не помог GuRun в Win 7 норм открывает, в Win 10 выдает Code 2 для URL

Comment: ERROR CODE 2 - "The specified file was not found".

Comment: про url: в процедуре перед if i<=32 можно добавить if not uppercase(copy(s,1,4))='HTTP' then ..

Comment: @Gu как это поможет открытию URL? Ошибку не будет выдавать при ХТТП, но и открывать не станет (

Comment: Все народ, разобрался, проблема была в том, что семерошному эксплореру плевать на лишние пробелы в URL! А EDGE браузер в 10 нет. По отладчику посмотрел внимательно, что у меня приходит в info_link и заметил пробел лишний, добавил info_link:=trim(info_link); и стало норм. Кто столкнется с такой же проблемой рекомендую проверить внимательно переменную!

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените посыл в гугл на прямую ссылку на документацию. Если по ссылке на ваш блог есть что-то важное - перенесите это прямо в ответ. Иначе ответ удалят как спам.